# I have .txt file as shown below I want to fetch all the string starting from keyword 'Min' till last '.'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have .txt file as shown below I want to fetch all the string starting from keyword 'Min' till last '.' in the file and dump it in another .txt file using python.

```
      Rahul            MIN Y(03).                               
       Annie          MIN Y(15).                               
      Amit             MIN Y(02).(gg).                               
       Jai                MIN Y(06).                               
     Antony              MIN Y(160).
```

Expected Output:
MIN Y(03).
MIN Y(15).
MIN Y(02).(gg).
MIN Y(06).
MIN Y(160).

Comment: please write the output expected from the .txt file you provided

Comment: Please explain how this is question is related to `python-requests`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/path/to/read/txt','r') as f:
    l=f.readlines()
    l1=[" ".join(i.partition('MIN')[1::]).strip(' ') for i in l ]
    f1=open('/path/to/write/txt','w')
    for i in l1:
        f1.write(i)
    f1.close()
```

you can use `partition` method on the list of strings

[str.partition(sep)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple
> containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and
> the part after the separator.

```
[('Rahul', 'MIN', ' Y(03). \n')........]
```

you can just join the last two tuples i.e from `MIN` and build a new string using `join`

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the most straightforward solution:

```
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f_in:
  with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        subline = line.split('MIN')[-1].split('.')[0]
        f_out.write(f'{subline}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal time to be using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```py
s = """      Rahul            MIN Y(03).                               
       Annie          MIN Y(15).                               
      Amit             MIN Y(02).(gg).                               
       Jai                MIN Y(06).                               
     Antony              MIN Y(160).
"""
# Import python's regex library
import re

# Create our pattern
pat = re.compile(r"(min.*\.)", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# Find all the pattern matches in the string `s`
for m in pat.findall(s):
    print(m)

# 'MIN Y(03).'
# 'MIN Y(15).'
# 'MIN Y(02).(gg).'
# 'MIN Y(06).'
# 'MIN Y(160).'
```

---

Here's how the regex `(min.*\.)` works:

- `(` opens a capture group
- `min` matches the characters `min` literally (case insensitive, because we used `re.IGNORECASE`)
- `.*` `.` matches any character and `*` tells it to match between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
- `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)